# visual studio, add new document type

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

How do i add a new document type to visual studio?
I need to add stringtemplate ".st" type of file, how do i do that? or is that even possible?
thank you very much

Comment: 2008 or 2010, i have both installed on my machine

Comment: Do you mean: how to add a file/document to an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET projects here's how you can create item templates, and this would then be available in new document dialog.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

For Visual C++ projects you would need this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xz4cw2.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what he asked. I need the same thing an none of the links helped.

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that Lina wanted to add an item template for .st file type. Lina's question apparently does not  make it clear. If you need a answer RedX, I would suggest that you or Lina answer JYelton's question and edit the question to make it clearer. I am sure StackOverflow has sufficient experts to help you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is exactly how you add a new file type. You create a new item template with the extension type of .st and then you associate that file type with visual studio using the file association option in the customize menu.